# Custom email notification by item based on product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, send, email-notifications

I have developed a custom code which sends e-mails to the customers based on the category of the product they buy. The problem with my site is one product is having many categories. The script is working correctly, other than that it sends many emails equal to the number of categories a product have. I want it to send only one e-mail per product.

Here is the code:

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "wcepp_notification_email");
function wcepp_notification_email( $order_id, $checkout = null ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if($order->status === 'processing' ) {

        function wcepp_get_custom_email_html( $order, $heading = false, $mailer, $cat_slug ) {
            $template = 'emails/woo-custom-emails-per-product-'.$cat_slug.'.php';
            return wc_get_template_html( $template, array(
                    'order'         => $order,
                    'email_heading' => $heading,
                    'sent_to_admin' => true,
                    'plain_text'    => false,
                    'email'         => $mailer
                )
            );
        }

        $liquify_array = array('cutting-agent', 'dabjuice-liquify');
        $terpene_array = array('terpene-blends', 'strain-specific', 'hybrid', 'indica', 'sativa', 'terpene-sample-kits', 'hybrid-sample-kit', 'indica-sample-kit', 'sativa-sample-kit');
        $isolates_array = array('raw-terpene-isolates', 'alpha', 'beta');

        // getting the order products
        $items = $order->get_items();

        // let's loop through each of the items
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $categories = get_the_terms( $item['product_id'] , 'product_cat' );

            foreach( $categories as $categorie ) {
                $cat_slug = $categorie->slug;

                if(in_array($cat_slug, $liquify_array)) {
                    $new_cat_slug = 'liquify';
                } elseif(in_array($cat_slug, $terpene_array)) {
                    $new_cat_slug = 'terpenes';
                } elseif(in_array($cat_slug, $isolates_array)) {
                    $new_cat_slug = 'isolates';
                }

                if(isset($new_cat_slug)) {
                    // Create a mailer
                    $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

                    //Prepare Email
                    $recipient = $order->billing_email;

                    if($new_cat_slug == 'liquify') {
                        $subject = 'Instructions for usage of your Liquify Product';
                    } elseif($new_cat_slug == 'terpenes') {
                        $subject = 'Instructions for usage of your Terpenes Product';
                    } elseif($new_cat_slug == 'isolates') {
                        $subject = 'Instructions for usage of your Raw Terpenes Isolates';
                    }

                    $content = wcepp_get_custom_email_html( $order, $subject, $mailer, $new_cat_slug );
                    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";

                    //send the email through wordpress
                    $mailer->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help in this regard will be appraciated.

Comment: It should be useful for others if you could add the code of your custom email template. Thanks.

Comment: My custom e-mail template is an HTML file which contains only text instruction for the product.

Comment: Add it anyways in your question please.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is outdated since Woocommerce 3 and have many mistakes. If you enable the debug on Wordpress you will get a lot of error messages. Try the following instead that will send an email for each product when it matches with a defined product category:

```
// Get email content from the custom template
function get_custom_email_content_html( $order, $heading = false, $mailer, $category_slug ) {
    $template = 'emails/woo-custom-emails-per-product-'.$category_slug.'.php';
    return wc_get_template_html( $template, array(
            'order'         => $order,
            'email_heading' => $heading,
            'sent_to_admin' => true,
            'plain_text'    => false,
            'email'         => $mailer
        )
    );
}

// Send a custom email notification for each order item on order processing status change
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'processing_custom_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function processing_custom_email_notification( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order ) {

    if( $status_to === 'processing' ) {

        $liquify_array = array('cutting-agent', 'dabjuice-liquify');
        $terpene_array = array('terpene-blends', 'strain-specific', 'hybrid', 'indica', 'sativa', 'terpene-sample-kits', 'hybrid-sample-kit', 'indica-sample-kit', 'sativa-sample-kit');
        $isolates_array = array('raw-terpene-isolates', 'alpha', 'beta');

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product_category = '';
            $categories_slugs = get_the_terms( $item->get_product_id() , 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

            foreach( $categories_slugs as $term_slug ) {
                if( in_array( $term_slug, $liquify_array ) ) {
                    $product_category = 'liquify';
                    break;
                } elseif(in_array( $term_slug, $terpene_array ) ) {
                    $product_category = 'terpenes';
                    break;
                } elseif(in_array( $term_slug, $isolates_array ) ) {
                    $product_category = 'isolates';
                    break;
                }
            }

            if( isset( $product_category ) ) {
                // Email subject
                if( $product_category == 'liquify' ) {
                    $subject = __("Instructions for usage of your Liquify Product");
                } elseif($product_category  == 'terpenes' ) {
                    $subject = __("Instructions for usage of your Terpenes Product");
                } elseif( $product_category == 'isolates' ) {
                    $subject = __("Instructions for usage of your Raw Terpenes Isolates");
                }
                $mailer    = WC()->mailer(); // Get an instance of the WC_Emails Object
                $recipient = $order->get_billing_email(); // Email recipient
                $content   = get_custom_email_content_html( $order, $subject, $mailer, $product_category ); // Email content (template)
                $headers   = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"; // Email headers

                // Send the email
                WC()->mailer()->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should better work now *(but not tested with your product categories)*.

> 3 custom email templates should be located in the `woocommerce` *folder* > `emails` *subfolder (of the active theme)*: 
>   `woo-custom-emails-per-product-liquify.php` 
>   `woo-custom-emails-per-product-terpenes.php` 
>   `woo-custom-emails-per-product-isolates.php`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but will it sends all the three emails, if an order have products from all the main categories?

Comment: @ShahidKhattak You are asking in your question to have an email notification by product (order item) based on your defined product categories. My answer code will take the first matching product category (which defines the subject and certainly the content) and will send an email by product (if there is a matching product category). **So it send 1 email by product.**

Comment: This code is sending an email with an error message, The message is here

Comment: Notice
: wc_get_template was called incorrectly. /home2/amayfield/test.adriennemayfield.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/woo-custom-emails-per-product-.php does not exist. Backtrace: edit_post, wp_update_post, wp_insert_post, do_action('save_post'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->save_meta_boxes, do_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::save, WC_Order->save, WC_Order->status_transition, do_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed'), WP_Hook->do_action,

Comment: The full error message cannot be copied, but you can clearly see that it is not adding that category slug suffix to the email template name.

Comment: @ShahidKhattak I have updated the answer code… (that was happening as I have renamed some variables and forgot to set the correct variable name in the template url that is called).

Comment: I have added a line at line no 40 and 41, which is      else{
                    $product_category = 'nothing';    and it is now sending the error message in the email and picking up the word "nothing" as the suffix, which means that for some reason the category is not matched with any of the categories arrays. Please note that I have not changed any product or any category on that testing site.

Comment: Sir I am waiting or your kind response, if you can help with this. Thanks

Comment: @LiocTheAztec I am debugging the code, and I have made a conclusion that the variable $product_category is having some value but it is not the value we want. It is having a value because an e-mail is sent, but it is not returning the value for some reason, because the sent email has the error, in which it is not adding that category slug suffix to the template name.

Comment: @LiocTheAztec Now I am unable to find what the $product_category variable is having, because it is set, but not having any value.